# How to share data between individual components in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two components `component 1` and `component 2`, they are individual components. `component 1` is not a parent of `component 2` and vice versa. Here i would to pass data from `component 2` to `component 1`. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

mini project use eventBus, others, I think you should use vuex